# Storing an unregistered Class in a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, runtime, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

In my code, I'm dynamically creating classes, and trying to store them in a NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary* classDict = [ [ NSMutableDictionary alloc ] init ];  

...start loop

Class customClass = objc_allocateClassPair( [ TestClass class ], className, 0 );

[ classDict setObject:customClass forKey:name ]

...end loop

...add methods to certain classes within the dict

...register classes with objective c
```

When I run the code, a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" is thrown when it's trying to add the Class to the dictionary. Is there a way to get around this? That is, is there a way to add a unregistered Class to a NSMutableDictionary? The alternative solution is to use a std:map data structure instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the actual question: adding a `Class` object to a dictionary is simple:

```
[dict setObject:[TestClass class] forKey:@"key"];
```

And I do so often, without any issue. However, you seem to want to add an unfinished class object. The documentation states:

> When you are done building the class, call objc_registerClassPair. The
>   new class is now ready for use.

So maybe your `Class` object is not "ready for use" yet?

**update** after some tests:

you need to call `objc_registerClassPair` in order to use `Class` as an actual object. Calling `retain` before this time will lead to an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

If you want to create classes in a loop, and register them in a later stage, just box the pointers, using:

```
[classDict setObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:customClass] forKey:name];
```

simply unbox them using `Class customClass = [value pointerValue];`. After registering you can of course use the `Class` objects as usual.

Comment: Yes, I guess I should have phrased my question differently. As you said, adding a class is easy. What I want to do is add an unregistered class to the data structure - if the fact that it's not "ready for use" is causing the problem, than I don't see many options.

Comment: Did you test if adding it to a dictionary after `obj_registerClassPair` give the same crash?

Comment: Yeah, and the code worked just fine. However, I need to add methods to the classes within the dict, before they are registered.

Comment: Well, apparently you can dynamically add methods to classes, after objc_registerClassPair has been called. I was under the impression that the class became immutable once it was registered. This fixes my problem. :)

Comment: well, you can always save the pointers to the unfinished objects, see my update.

Comment: Your update was exactly the solution I was looking for when I wrote the question - thanks! The idea of registering classes before the methods are established seems odd to me, so I think I'll take this approach.